# Fatal error: Could not convert the script from the detected encoding "UTF-32LE"

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, freebsd

Copied a working website from one server to another, now I'm getting this error - browsing to the main page of the website.

```
Fatal error: Could not convert the script from the detected encoding "UTF-32LE" 
  to a compatible encoding in /usr/local/share/zf/library/Zend/Application.php 
  on line 320
```

And the global `httpd-error.log` shows, the server is runnign other vhosts, but pretty sure it's related to the above error.

```
[notice] child pid 8012 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

The servers both run FreeBSD 8.1, one 32bit (with error) and the other 64bit. Just updated the one having the error to newest versions of Apache and PHP, available in Ports-catalog. Error also occurred before update.

Please note that, my intention of the copy is to use large parts for a new website, so have been doing some deletion of files, but should not have any impact on the error above.

Comment: Is it possible that there was a problem when copying the data over from one server to the other? Possibly the transfer mode? In addition is there any difference between the server configurations that could cause this?

Comment: First I just tar'ed the files and transfered via http with fetch, and extracted the files. This also gave me some issues with permissions, so i tar'ed them on the new server, and dowloaded the tarbal to my Mac, and uploaded them again via FTP. This fixed the persimissions problem. But the error still persist. Later tonight I will try downloading the files directly from the old server to the macbook and upload them to the new server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I had to remove everything again, download the tar with the website from the origin server to my mac. Extracted on my mac, and uploaded to new server with FTP - now the error is gone.